# Как создать временные виджеты в PyQt5 с QtDesigner?

Tags: python, pyqt5, анимация, gui, qt-designer

[image]

Есть интерфейс с красивой анимацией, которую помог сделать один добрый человек. Внутри фрейма, когда он находится в широком состоянии, я хотел бы разместить лейблы с заголовками страниц рядом с кнопками, которые на них ведут или увеличить размер кнопок на всю ширину фрейма так, чтобы в развёрнутом состоянии можно было видеть не только иконку, но и рядом с ней - подпись.

Прилагаю основной код приложения и код функционала анимации (код интерфейса не влез).

1. **AsQamm.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

from _asQamm import *
from _asQamm.asQammUI import Ui_MainWindow
from _asQamm.resources import *
from _asQamm.functions import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.btnToggle.clicked.connect(lambda: UIFunctions.toggleMenu(self, 190, True))

        # Cкин Дом
        self.ui.btn_page1.clicked.connect( lambda: selectSkin(1, self.ui) )

        # Скин Защита
        self.ui.btn_page2.clicked.connect( lambda: selectSkin(2, self.ui) )

        # Скин Растения
        self.ui.btn_page3.clicked.connect( lambda: selectSkin(3, self.ui) )

        # Скин Управление
        self.ui.btn_page4.clicked.connect( lambda: selectSkin(4, self.ui) )

        # Скин Конфигурации
        self.ui.btn_page5.clicked.connect( lambda: selectSkin(5, self.ui) )



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    root = MainWindow()
    root.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

2. **functions.py**:

```
from AsQamm import *

class UIFunctions(MainWindow):

    def toggleMenu(self, maxWidth, enable):
        if enable:

            # получаем ширину фрейма
            width = self.ui.frame_left_menu.width()
            maxExtend = maxWidth
            standard = 60

            # установим максимальное значение ширины фрейма
            if width == 60:
                widthExtended = maxExtend
            else:
                widthExtended = standard

            # выполним анимацию
            self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self.ui.frame_left_menu, b"minimumWidth")
            self.animation.setDuration(200)
            self.animation.setStartValue(width)
            self.animation.setEndValue(widthExtended)
            self.animation.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.InOutQuart)
            self.animation.start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я увидел вашу задачу так:

**q1159170.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

from ui_main import Ui_MainWindow
from ui_functions import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # TOGGLE/BURGUER MENU
        self.ui.Btn_Toggle.clicked.connect(lambda: UIFunctions.toggleMenu(self, 250, True))

        # PAGE 1
        self.ui.btn_page_1.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.page_1))

        # PAGE 2
        self.ui.btn_page_2.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.page_2))

        # PAGE 3
        self.ui.btn_page_3.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.page_3))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**ui_main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1000, 500)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1000, 500))
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(45, 45, 45);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.Top_Bar = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.Top_Bar.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 40))
        self.Top_Bar.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);")
        self.Top_Bar.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.Top_Bar.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.Top_Bar.setObjectName("Top_Bar")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.Top_Bar)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.frame_toggle = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Top_Bar)
        self.frame_toggle.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(70, 40))
        self.frame_toggle.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255);")
        self.frame_toggle.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_toggle.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_toggle.setObjectName("frame_toggle")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_toggle)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.Btn_Toggle = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_toggle)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.Btn_Toggle.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.Btn_Toggle.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.Btn_Toggle.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border: 0px solid;")
        self.Btn_Toggle.setObjectName("Btn_Toggle")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.Btn_Toggle)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.frame_toggle)
        self.frame_top = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Top_Bar)
        self.frame_top.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_top.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_top.setObjectName("frame_top")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.frame_top)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Top_Bar)
        self.Content = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.Content.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.Content.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.Content.setObjectName("Content")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.Content)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.frame_left_menu = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_left_menu.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(70, 0))
        self.frame_left_menu.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(70, 16777215))
        self.frame_left_menu.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);")
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_left_menu.setObjectName("frame_left_menu")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.frame_top_menus = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_top_menus.setObjectName("frame_top_menus")
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_top_menus)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")

        
        '''
        self.btn_page_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.btn_page_1.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);\n"
"    border: 0px solid;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255);\n"
"}")
        self.btn_page_1.setObjectName("btn_page_1")
        
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_1)
        '''
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.w_page_1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()   
        self.btn_page_1 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_1.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('heart.png'))
        self.btn_page_1.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50)) 
        
        self.lbl_page_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Hello World", self.frame_top_menus) 
        self.lbl_page_1.setStyleSheet('color: #fff')
        self.lbl_page_1.hide()
        
        h_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.w_page_1)
        h_layout.addWidget(self.btn_page_1, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        h_layout.addWidget(self.lbl_page_1, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)

        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.w_page_1)        
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        

        self.btn_page_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.btn_page_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);\n"
"    border: 0px solid;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255);\n"
"}")
        self.btn_page_2.setObjectName("btn_page_2")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_2)
        self.btn_page_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.btn_page_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);\n"
"    border: 0px solid;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255);\n"
"}")
        self.btn_page_3.setObjectName("btn_page_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_3)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_top_menus, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.frame_pages = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_pages.setObjectName("frame_pages")
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_pages)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.frame_pages)
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        self.page_1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_1.setObjectName("page_1")
        self.verticalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_1)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setObjectName("verticalLayout_7")
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page_1)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        self.label_1.setFont(font)
        self.label_1.setStyleSheet("color: #FFF;")
        self.label_1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.label_1)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_1)
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_2)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName("verticalLayout_6")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: #FFF;")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        self.page_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_3.setObjectName("page_3")
        self.verticalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_3)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setObjectName("verticalLayout_8")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: #FFF;")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.label)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_3)
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_pages)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Content)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.Btn_Toggle.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TOGGLE"))
        self.btn_page_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Page 1"))
        self.btn_page_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Page 2"))
        self.btn_page_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Page 3"))
        self.label_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PAGE 1"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PAGE 2"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PAGE 3"))
```

**ui_functions.py**

```
from q1159170 import *

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
def take_screenshot(self, width):
    if width == 70:
        self.ui.lbl_page_1.show()
    else:
        self.ui.lbl_page_1.hide() 
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

class UIFunctions(MainWindow):

    def toggleMenu(self, maxWidth, enable):
        if enable:

            # GET WIDTH
            width = self.ui.frame_left_menu.width()
            maxExtend = maxWidth
            standard = 70

            # SET MAX WIDTH
            if width == 70:
                widthExtended = maxExtend
            else:
                widthExtended = standard

            # ANIMATION
            self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self.ui.frame_left_menu, b"minimumWidth")
            self.animation.setDuration(400)
            self.animation.setStartValue(width)
            self.animation.setEndValue(widthExtended)
            self.animation.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.InOutQuart)
            self.animation.start()

            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(200, lambda: take_screenshot(self, width))         # +++
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Обратите внимание на изменения, которые я внес в модулях: `ui_main.py` и `ui_functions.py`.

Comment: Неплохо. Но есть проблема: чтобы применить эти изменения, нужно редактировать исходный код интерфейса уже после конвертации из формата `ui`, то есть QtDesigner применить не получится

Comment: Есть ещё одна подруга в Вашем решении: вы вносите дополнения в файл `ui-main.py` после его компиляции при помощи `pyuic`. Это означает, что если позже вы произведёте повторно компиляцию из ui-файла, то ваш дополнительный код будет исчезать. Я пытаюсь осуществить ваши дополнения при помощи методов из другого модуля, однако отрисовка виджетов происходит в обратном порядке и с неправильными иконками на кнопках