# Переключение страниц в PySide2

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, pyqt, pyside2

В моем приложении на данный момент окна с содержимым переключаются при помощи табов.
Вопрос: как сделать переключение кнопками, а не табами?

Простой пример как сейчас реализована суть

**UI_test.py**

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt,QPointF
from PySide2.QtCharts import QtCharts

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.tabWidget.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.tabWidget.setMinimumSize(640, 480)
        self.tabWidget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")

        self.tab1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab1.setObjectName("tab1")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab1, "tab1")

        self.tab2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab2.setObjectName("tab2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab2, "tab2")

        self.grid_main = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.grid_main.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        Form.setLayout(self.grid_main)
```

**app.py**

```
from UI_test import Ui_Form
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import qdarkgraystyle
import sys

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    app.setStyleSheet(qdarkgraystyle.load_stylesheet())
    app.setStyle('Windows')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Как я хочу устроить:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно, слева кнопки, которыми можно переключать контент в окне. Вот так я бы хотел реализовать вместо табов.
Можно ли какой-нибудь базовый пример переключения контента кнопками? Спасибо

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1089514/pyqt-5-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%b2-qlistwidget/1089535#1089535 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1154322/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b5-%d0%b2-qt-designer/1154355#1154355

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1092931/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-qtabwidget-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bcpyqt-5-python-3/1092979#1092979

Comment: Отличные примеры! Спасибо!

Comment: Newman пожалуйста. это не все что вы можете тут найти. Если вам что-то будет очень полезно и узнаете что-то новое, не стесняйтесь отмечать ответы как полезный.

Comment: Newman бонусом для вас: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1154322, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1159170, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1161906/

Comment: По второй ссылке тоже збс пример. Благодарю!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для левой половины можно использовать `QVBoxLayout`+`QPushButton`, для правой половины `QStackedWidget`

При клике на кнопки переключаете страницу через `setCurrentIndex` или `setCurrentWidget`

Пример:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QStackedWidget


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.stacked_widget = QStackedWidget()
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(QLabel('1234'))
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(QLabel('ABCD'))
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(QLabel('FOO_BAR'))

        self.button_123 = QPushButton('1234')
        self.button_123.clicked.connect(lambda: self.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex(0))

        self.button_ABCD = QPushButton('ABCD')
        self.button_ABCD.clicked.connect(lambda: self.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex(1))

        self.button_FOO_BAR = QPushButton('FOO_BAR')
        self.button_FOO_BAR.clicked.connect(lambda: self.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex(2))

        layout_buttons = QVBoxLayout()
        layout_buttons.addWidget(self.button_123)
        layout_buttons.addWidget(self.button_ABCD)
        layout_buttons.addWidget(self.button_FOO_BAR)

        main_layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        main_layout.addLayout(layout_buttons)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.stacked_widget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Еще вариант, но для левой половины используется `QListWidget`:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QLabel, QStackedWidget, QListWidget


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.stacked_widget = QStackedWidget()
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(QLabel('1234'))
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(QLabel('ABCD'))
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(QLabel('FOO_BAR'))

        self.control_list = QListWidget()
        self.control_list.addItems(['1234', 'ABCD', 'FOO_BAR'])
        self.control_list.setFixedWidth(80)
        self.control_list.clicked.connect(lambda index: self.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex(index.row()))

        main_layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.control_list)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.stacked_widget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!